# How to transform xls file with merged columns to csv?

Tags: excel, csv, file, transform, xls

I'm trying to transform some .xls files to .csv, and one of the files has some merged columns. When I do the transformation, only one value is returned. This image will explain the situation:
[image: Problem in image]

Comment: You cannot. CSV format is not rich enough to support merged column. What do you want to achieve with the conversion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should unmerge cells in your .xls file. The given code will unmerge cells properly.

[image: before - merged] **==>>** [image: after - unmerged]

1. Open your sheet.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Insert => Module
4. Paste this code:

```vb
Sub activesheet_unmerge()
  Dim c As Range
  Dim c2 As Range
  Dim rMergeArea As Range
  Dim vMergeValue As Variant
  For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If c.MergeCells Then
      Set rMergeArea = c.MergeArea
      vMergeValue = c.Value
      rMergeArea.unmerge
      For Each c2 In rMergeArea
        c2.Value = vMergeValue
      Next
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

5. Put the mouse pointer somewhere in the middle of this code and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the code.