# R - Transforming a CSV file from a unique format to a standard dataframe

Tags: r, import, transform

I had earlier asked this question, but am adjusting the question today to provide clarity.

I am working on a script that requires the variables of treatment, subject, body mass, and date.
As of right now, the data linked here is the format I need to be working with. Please note, here each measurement is unique by subject and date. I am primarily interested in using "body_mass_g" for modelling later, for context.

```
   exp cohort    sbj treatment     date time body_mass_g food_weight_g blood_glucose_mgdl
1  dtx   tx03 dtx001      A    1/7/2020   NA       30.70            NA                 NA
2  dtx   tx03 dtx002      B    1/7/2020   NA       30.67            NA                 NA
3  dtx   tx03 dtx006      A    1/7/2020   NA       28.93            NA                 NA
4  dtx   tx03 dtx007      A    1/7/2020   NA       28.73            NA                 NA
5  dtx   tx03 dtx008      B    1/7/2020   NA       25.56            NA                 NA
6  dtx   tx03 dtx009      B    1/7/2020   NA       24.79            NA                 NA
7  dtx   tx03 dtx010      A    1/7/2020   NA       27.13            NA                 NA
8  dtx   tx03 dtx011      B    1/7/2020   NA       27.32            NA                 NA
9  dtx   tx03 dtx012      B    1/7/2020   NA       27.28            NA                 NA
10 dtx   tx03 dtx013      B    1/7/2020   NA       29.56            NA                 NA
```

However, **my problem currently is a new format of csv file data that I need to convert to the above format**. The new format is shown below. R interprets my new data in a very confusing manner, so I am attaching example code below. The date columns contain nested subcolumns with body_mass_g, my variable of interest. This doesn't show the date in one column, but instead as large blocks with nested columns, stretching across each row of subject and treatment. There are more dates stretching to the right. For your reference, I can also attack an image after the data below.

```
                       |   1/1/2023, Monday Day 0  |   1/2/2023, Tuesday Day 1  
1 Tag  sbj.  Treatment |  body_mass_g   BG  Hopper |  body_mass_g   BG  Hopper
2 10   1     A         |  22            1   6      |  22            1   6
3 12   2     B         |  21            3   5      |  21            3   5
4 12   2     A         |  11            3   7      |  11            3   7
5 13   1     B         |  33            2   8      |  33            2   8
6 12   2     A         |  44            1   9      |  44            1   9
```

Image showing my true new dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BYV9.png

I have really just tried importing it using "read.csv", but somehow R imports this in an extremely odd format, creating new columns and tacking an "X" onto every column header. I get stuck at this stage due to the odd format in which it creates the dataframe in the first place.

I'd appreciate any help. Please let me know if there's more information I can provide. Thank you.

Updated Code below. This code was very helpful in providing the right organization of code, but returns all values as  or only the class of each value (excluding the Date) in the "output" dataframe. I believe this is an issue with pivot_wider, but how can I fix this?

```
df2 <- read_excel(file_name, sheet = 1, skip = 1)
# Extract the first row and manipulate it to combine it with the
# column names.
col_name_groups <-
  read_excel(file_name, sheet = 1, col_names = FALSE) |>
  slice(1) |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  fill(value) |>
  replace_na(list(value = "")) |>
  pull(value)

# Clean up column names
col_names <-
  names(df2) |>
  str_remove("\\.\\.\\.[0-9]")

# Combine first and second rows of column names
col_names <-
  paste(col_name_groups, col_names, sep = "#") |>
  str_remove("^#")

# Apply combined column names, pivot data and extract the date column
output <- capture.output ({
df2 |>
  set_names(col_names) |>
  rename_with(~str_remove(., "[0-9]+$")) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Eartag, Mouse, Inj.),
               names_to = c("group", "var"),
               names_sep = "#") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = var,
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = unlist) |>
  mutate(date = str_extract(group, "(.*)(,)", group = 1)) |> 
  select(Mouse, date, BW, BG, Hopper)
})
```

Comment: You could try 1) unmerging cells in Excel (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430111/how-to-transform-xls-file-with-merged-columns-to-csv) for an example). 2)Then you could create your data frame from either xlsx or csv format, and assemble `colnames()` using the header + first row.

Comment: Is it definitely a .csv file extension? One issue could be the additional commas in the header row (since R interprets these as different columns if using read.csv).

Comment: It is also an excel file. However, importing both files ends up having the same result. It shows the originally nested columns as new column, and fails to keep the date association. Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the first row when reading the data from the XLSX file and
paste the first row values with the column names. Then, you can pivot the
data into the desired format and extract the date column.

The code below should work with your data. Just replace the file name
with your file name.

First, I create an Excel file that resembles the structure of yours:

```r
library(openxlsx)
     
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    id = 1:10,
    body_mass_g = 11:20,
    BG = 21:30,
    Hopper = 1:10,
    body_mass_g = 11:20,
    BG = 21:30,
    Hopper = 1:10,
    check.names = FALSE
  )

first_colname_row <-
  c("", "1/1/2023, Monday Day 0", "", "", "1/2/2023, Monday Day 1") |>
  matrix(nrow = 1)

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
writeData(wb, "sheet1", df1, startRow = 2)
writeData(wb, "sheet1", first_colname_row, colNames = FALSE)
mergeCells(wb, "sheet1", 2:4, 1)
mergeCells(wb, "sheet1", 5:7, 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, "merged_header_cells.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This is the relevant code for you:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

file_name <- "merged_header_cells.xlsx"

# Read the data, skipping the first row
df2 <- read_excel(file_name, sheet = 1, skip = 1)

# Extract the first row and manipulate it to combine it with the
# column names.
col_name_groups <-
  read_excel(file_name, sheet = 1, col_names = FALSE) |>
  slice(1) |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  fill(value) |>
  replace_na(list(value = "")) |>
  pull(value)

# Clean up column names
col_names <-
  names(df2) |>
  str_remove("\\.\\.\\.[0-9]")

# Combine first and second rows of column names
col_names <-
  paste(col_name_groups, col_names, sep = "#") |>
  str_remove("^#")

# Apply combined column names, pivot data and extract the date column
df2 |>
  set_names(col_names) |>
  pivot_longer(-id,
               names_to = c("group", "var"),
               names_sep = "#") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = var,
              values_from = value) |>
  mutate(date = str_extract(group, "(.*)(,)", group = 1)) |> 
  select(id, date, body_mass_g, BG, Hopper)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#>       id date     body_mass_g    BG Hopper
#>    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 1/1/2023          11    21      1
#>  2     1 1/2/2023          11    21      1
#>  3     2 1/1/2023          12    22      2
#>  4     2 1/2/2023          12    22      2
#>  5     3 1/1/2023          13    23      3
#>  6     3 1/2/2023          13    23      3
#>  7     4 1/1/2023          14    24      4
#>  8     4 1/2/2023          14    24      4
#>  9     5 1/1/2023          15    25      5
#> 10     5 1/2/2023          15    25      5
#> 11     6 1/1/2023          16    26      6
#> 12     6 1/2/2023          16    26      6
#> 13     7 1/1/2023          17    27      7
#> 14     7 1/2/2023          17    27      7
#> 15     8 1/1/2023          18    28      8
#> 16     8 1/2/2023          18    28      8
#> 17     9 1/1/2023          19    29      9
#> 18     9 1/2/2023          19    29      9
#> 19    10 1/1/2023          20    30     10
#> 20    10 1/2/2023          20    30     10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This has gotten me so much farther. However, when I use this, I am ending up with unique "body_mass_g", "BW", and "Hopper" names for each date. Somehow they are still filtering into different columns based on the original date, for example, as "BW..1", "BW..2", "BW..3" and so on for the others as well. There is no one date column, either. Would you know if there's an easy fix for this, or just something I have to tweak in the code on my own?

Comment: Try excluding all columns not under a merged first-row name from the `pivot_longer()` call. Something like this: `... pivot_longer(-c(tag, Subject, Treatment), ...) ...`

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting to a point where I end up with exactly the format I want, but the thing is that all the values returned in each column are shown as "dbl" or "null", which is really just the class of the values, not the actual values from category (BG, Hopper, etc.). Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: Please add your current code to your question or post a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the code I used at the end of my question, largely based on the code you provided earlier. Please let me know if you think there's any fix with final dataframe "output".